# how to copy a penultimate file from a SSH to local using a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm new in bash scripting and I'm trying to make a script which can copy a penultimate file from a folder, from machine B (ssh) to machine A (local).
For now I'm stuck at this point (see below) when I'm receiving an error when the script trying to copy the file.

Thank you in advance!

**Input:**

```
#!/bin/bash

userName=`whoami`
myLocation=`pwd`  #machineA or local

ssh $userName@machineB << 'ENDSSH'
pathFile="/somefolder/folder_1/businessfolder/"
cd $pathFile
ls -ltrh
zipFile=`ls -Art | tail -n 2 | head -1`
echo $zipFile
ENDSSH
scp $userName@machineB:$pathFile$zipFile $myLocation
```

**Output (just error):**

```
scp: .: not a regular file
```

Comment: You may want to paste your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and correct what it bemoans; for starters you're not terminating the here-document.

Comment: @tink yeah I made some mistake, thank you for the point. I corrected now. Although, Why last line cannot be run? :(

Comment: pathFile and zipFile  are unknown in the script outside the ssh-session.

Comment: Is there any possibility to export those "data" (pathFile and zipFile) outside the SSH-session?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: What kind of file is a _penulitmate_ file? In any case, I would run for debugging your script with `-x` turned on, to see what is happening.

Comment: You could inside your ssh-session write the content of the variable `zipFile` to some file and then read this file with `scp`. In your main session, you read this file (with `scp`) and then know the real file name which you want to transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can `touch ~/.hushlogin` on `machineB` for `userName` the following **should** work (worked for me):

```
#!/bin/bash
userName=$(whoami)
myLocation=$(pwd)
pathFile="/somefolder/folder_1/businessfolder/"

zipFile=$(ssh -T -q $userName@machineB <<ENDSSH
cd $pathFile
ls -Art | tail -n 2 | head -1
ENDSSH
)
scp "$userName"@machineB:"$pathFile$zipFile" "$myLocation"
```

Comment: For the safe side, I would guard the `scp` with a `[[ -n $zipFile ]] && scp ...`, to catch the case that there are no entries in `$pathFile`, or that the `ssh` fails for different reasons.

Comment: That would require a second ssh connection to verify, and just add complexity. The failure mode is simple enough as it is.

Comment: Why do you need one more connection? `zipFile` is a variable on your host, and you test it there, just before doing the `scp`.

Comment: The variable may be on my host, but the file resides on the remote host. Testing for its existence requires an extra connection ...

Comment: No - you get this information for free. Let's assume that the directory is empty. The pipe in your ssh connection (in particular the `head` at the end) won't return anything. Therefore the `ssh` command does not print anything to stdout. Therefore the variable `zipFile` will be empty.